# deno inspect with docker compose

Tags: docker, debugging, docker-compose, deno

I am trying to inspect a deno app that is ran inside a docker container with docker-compose.

docker-compose configuration is as follows:

```
services:
  api_bo:
    image: denoland/deno:debian-1.23.4
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /usr/src
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
      - 6005:3000
    command: bash -c "cd /usr/src/packages/api_bo && deno task inspect"
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo_db:27017/academy_db
      - DB_NAME=academy_db
      - PORT=3000
```

deno.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "strict": true
  },
  "lint": {
    "files": {
      "include": ["src/"],
      "exclude": ["src/types.ts"]
    },
    "rules": {
      "tags": ["recommended"],
      "include": [
        "ban-untagged-todo",
        "no-explicit-any",
        "no-implicit-any",
        "explicit-function-return-type"
      ],
      "exclude": ["no-debugger", "no-console"]
    }
  },
  "tasks": {
    "start": "deno run -A --watch src/app.ts",
    "inspect": "deno run -A --inspect src/app.ts"
  },
  "importMap": "../../import_map.json"
}
```

Chrome with `chrome://inspect` does not detect the running process.

When running out of docker with deno run, it works just fine.

It seems that deno only listens to connections from `0.0.0.0` and thus it cannot be inspected using docker port forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deno and NodeJS share the same Inspector Protocol from V8, for more see [V8 / Docs / Inspector](https://v8.dev/docs/inspector).

And also (lucky) the same parameter "--inspect=[HOST:PORT]" and "--inspect-brk=[HOST:PORT]" so on,
for more see [NodeJS / API / Inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--inspecthostport) or [NodeJS / API / Inspect Brk](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--inspect-brkhostport) (THIS is the documentation from NODEJS, so be careful!)

The main "problem" (security reasons) is that NodeJS and Deno Inspector Protocol listen only to localhost / 127.0.0.1 and Docker can't and won't forward these ports. But with the parameter "--inspect" you can change the Host and Port.

### Deno CLI

```
deno run --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./src/my-big-cool-file.ts
```

### Dockerfile

```
# ...
EXPOSE 9229
# ...
CMD ["run", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229", "...", "./src/main.ts"]
```

## TLDR;

### your deno.json

```json
//...
  "tasks": {
    "start": "deno run -A --watch src/app.ts",
    "inspect": "deno run -A --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 src/app.ts"
  },
//...
```

### your docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  # ...
  api_bo:
    # ...
    ports:
      # THIS IS IMPORTANT, FORWARD DEBUG PROTOCOLS ONLY TO YOUR LOCALHOST! **1
      - 127.0.0.1:9229:9229
```

**1 except: when you need it, and you know what you are doing!!!